# Can't load libavcodec.so in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I can't load libavcodec.so in the android project, the log says dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "ff_vp9_copy32_aarch64" referenced by "/data/app/com.*.*-1/lib/arm64/libavcodec.so"..., the ffmpeg version is 4.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

try add "--enable--neon " as the one of arguments of "./configure" when you compile